# How to use MIConvexHull library

Tags: c#, generics, nuget-package, convex-hull

I am currently trying to implement convex hull calculation for my project and therefore, I installed the https://www.nuget.org/packages/MIConvexHull/ NuGet package. (This project is a convex hull algorithm and library for 2D, 3D, and higher dimensions.) Here is the link to the github page: https://github.com/DesignEngrLab/MIConvexHull

This is how far I have come and what I have done/understood so far:
For creating the convex hull, you need a list of vertices and then a convex hull is basically a list of vertices and a list of faces. So here is how I currently try to implement it.

```
List<Vertex> MI_convexHullVertices = new List<Vertex>();

var MI_convexHull = MIConvexHull.ConvexHull.Create<Vertex, Face>(vertices);
```

For this code, I get a lot of compiler errors though because there is no Vertex and no Face class. And I now don't know what to use here.

This is a part from the `ConvexHull` class inside ConvexHull.cs:

```
    public static ConvexHull<TVertex, TFace> Create<TVertex, TFace>(IList<TVertex> data,
        double PlaneDistanceTolerance = Constants.DefaultPlaneDistanceTolerance)
        where TVertex : IVertex
        where TFace : ConvexFace<TVertex, TFace>, new()
    {
        return ConvexHull<TVertex, TFace>.Create(data, PlaneDistanceTolerance);
    }
```

**And now here comes my question: Can someone explain to me what TVertex and TFace is? And after that, how to use the code?**

I feel like it has something to do with generic data types, like `TVertex` isn't a real type, but what exactly is it and what real class/type can I use to actually implement convex hull calculation?

The thing is, I don't know the syntax at the end there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what TVertex and TFace is? And after that,
>   how to use the code?

The `TVertex` and `TFace` are [constructed types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) and yes, this has to do with generics. When you call the static method `ConvexHull` you have to provide two instances, one that implements the interface `IVertex`, this is associated with the `TVertex`, and the other that inherits from `ConvexFace<TVertex, TFace>`, this is associated with the `TFace`.

If you looked inside the project's [github repository](https://github.com/DesignEngrLab/MIConvexHull), you would find a folder called *Examples*. There you would find how the library can be used. For instance, [here](https://github.com/DesignEngrLab/MIConvexHull/tree/master/Examples/1TestEXE%20for%20MIConvexHull-2D) you would find an illustrative example for the case of 2D Convex Hull.

In broad lines, it creates an array of vertices:

```
var vertices = new Vertex[NumberOfVertices];
```

and then it fills them with new `Vertex` objects, using the constructor of `Vertex` class

```
new Vertex(size * r.NextDouble(), size * r.NextDouble());
```

and then gets the points of the `ConvexHull` as simply as:

```
var convexHull = ConvexHull.Create(vertices).Points;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I looked through the examples, but the 3d one mostly, because that's what I need. There I did found the actual face and vertex class implementations, but because I didn't understand the whole picture, I got confused... But you made it very clear to me now thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've done a benchmark with many convex hull algorithms including MIConvexHull and mine. If you browse the provided code, you may find how to use the code for 2D usage:

[Fast and improved 2D Convex Hull algorithm and its implementation in O(n log h)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210225/Fast-and-improved-D-Convex-Hull-algorithm-and-its)